# production.ERROR: Class App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale does not exist in Laravel

Tags: laravel

My Laravel-5.8 application was working, but suddenly I got this error:

```
production.ERROR: Class App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale does not exist
```

and can't login again.

The SetLocale exists. This is it:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetLocale
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (request('change_language')) {
            session()->put('language', request('change_language'));
            $language = request('change_language');
        } elseif (session('language')) {
            $language = session('language');
        } elseif (config('panel.primary_language')) {
            $language = config('panel.primary_language');
        }

        if (isset($language)) {
            app()->setLocale($language);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the file's name is `SetLocale.php` and not something like `setlocale.php` or `Setlocale.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace seems correct and only thing I can think of is composer cache.

Try to run command `composer dumpautoload` at your project root directory to force the autoload file to regenerate.

Comment: I did composer dumpautoload, but the problem still remain

Answer (score 0):

To ensure proper configuration, please verify that the "kernel.php" file has "protected $routeMiddleware" set instead of "$aliasesMiddleware".